# Undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I still get this error for some I guess stupid reason. I was following Laracast fundamentals tutorials then I decided to create my own app and it's the same. Probably I've messed something up and can't see it.

Here's the error:

> Undefined variable: movies (View: C:\Users\username\PhpstormProjects\movie_app\resources\views\movies\show.blade.php)

This is my controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $movie = Movie::findOrFail($id);
    return view('movies.show', compact('movie'));
}
```

View:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @foreach($movies as $movie)
        <h4>{{$movie->name}}</h4>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: your vairable is `$movie` not `$movies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not returning collection you can't use `foreach`.

To `echo` the movie call the object name directly:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
   <h4>{{$movie->name}}</h4>
@endsection
```

And yet you call wrong variable name at your view. You return `movie` not `movies`.

Comment: Got that:
"Trying to get property of non-object"
If I change the controller I still get the same error :(.

Comment: my bad. wait will fix my answer

Comment: I've update my answer. try that one

Comment: It worked. So, If I have the only one movie in my database it won't work because it isn't a collection yet, correct?

Comment: nope. It's not depend on the database. You can have 500 movies but the problem is on what are your query return the result. You return it in single item not a collection. read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models

Comment: Thank you, now I get it.